# How to check if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, haml, undefined

I am using HAML and jquery to code my application. I have a single 'Share' template that is used to display a URL link. I want it to be flexible such that it will display different URLs depending on the variables that are passed into it.

```
//Code to trigger view and populate template -> Note I only pass in the thread vara here
share_view = new Onethingaday.Views.Threads.ShareView
  thread: new Onethingaday.Models.Thread(@options.thread_muses.first().get('question'))

//snippet from share view to pass the variables to the template
render: ->
  $(@el).html @template
    nickname: @options.nickname
    thread_slug: @options.thread.get('slug')
    thread_text: @options.thread.get('text')
  @

//Snippet of share view's template. Added if-else statement to check if nickname is defined
.sidebar_text Link:
  <% if (typeof <%= nickname %> !== "undefined") { %>
  %input.detail_text{value: "<%= 'http://dailymus.es/' + nickname + '/threads/' + thread_slug %>"}
  <% } else { %>
  %input.detail_text{value: "<%= 'http://dailymus.es/' + '/threads/' + thread_slug %>"}
  <% } %>
```

In the above example, I did not define "nickname" variable. I expect that the else portion will be triggered and the URL displayed is "http://dailymus.es/threads/some-slug-text"

However I am still getting the following

[image]

As you see, it is still triggering the 'if' portion and displaying the 'undefined' as part of the URL.

How can I correctly check for 'undefined' variables in my case?

Comment: Maybe "nickname" is getting set to null?  In that case its type would be "object" and not "undefined".

Comment: do you still need to wrap `nickname` in `<%=%>` when it's already in one?

Comment: @dbaseman, I did a console log console.log(typeof @options.nickname) and the result gave me 'undefined'

Comment: are you sure of condition operator !== or !=

Comment: @Karthi.L I tried both and they didn't work

Comment: @rkw, you are right! I didn't have to wrap the nickname in <%= %>. Can you add that as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still need to wrap nickname in <%=%> when it's already in one?